# htaccess combine specific and general redirection issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Changing domains from ExampleShop.com to ExampleStore.com

I'm having an issue trying to redirect about 30 specific pages and also do a generic redirect for the pages where the URL mapping hasn't changed just the domain.

Here is what I have, it is redirecting everything using the generic rewrite rule and not redirecting the specic rewrites.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#Specialty Rewrites for non-exact mapped URLs
RewriteRule ^/gifts/jewellery/bracelets.html$ http://www.ExampleStore.com/gifts/jewellery/bracelets.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/gifts/watches/banded.html$ http://www.ExampleStore.com/gifts-for-him/jewellery/watches.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Generic Rewrite for exact mapped URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ExampleStore.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^gifts/jewellery/bracelets.html$ http://www.ExampleStore.com/gifts/jewellery/bracelets.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^gifts/watches/banded.html$ http://www.ExampleStore.com/gifts-for-him/jewellery/watches.html [R=301,L]
```

`.htaccess` is per directory directives and Apache removes leading slash from URI while being used in `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked that!